# Need help how to achieve this multiple array to be inserted to database in Php Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to import the XML data to my database. But I have a hard time to loop  it all since the array are not the same layer.

I tried foreach but some of the data are not inserted although the keys of each data are the same.

here is the current output array

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "001"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "0011023036"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
      "BANFN" => "0011022474"
      "BNFPO" => "00010"
      "LIFNR_ID" => "0000003468"
      "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
        "MSGTYP" => "E"
        "MSG" => "random text"
      ]
    ]
    1 => array:4 [▼
      "BANFN" => "0011022474"
      "BNFPO" => "00010"
      "LIFNR_ID" => "0000003468"
      "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
        "MSGTYP" => "S"
        "MSG" => "random text"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

here is the code that I want to be achieve

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "0011023037"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "0011023036"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
2 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "0011023036"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
3 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "0011023036"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
4 => array:4 [▼
    "BANFN" => "0011023036"
    "BNFPO" => "00010"
    "LIFNR_ID" => "0000001244"
    "STATUS" => array:2 [▼
      "MSGTYP" => "S"
      "MSG" => "random text"
    ]
  ]
]
```

I need to flatten the array on the same layer with keys. But I can't figure it. Or is there any methods for foreach or looping that all of the arrays will be inserted to the database?

The code to create the original array is

```
$url = Storage::disk('ftp')->allFiles('PM/PR_RFQNUM/'); 
$v = []; 
foreach ($url as $key => $files) { 
    //$file[] = $files; 
    $xml = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($files); 
    $file = Formatter::make($xml, Formatter::XML)->toArray(); 
    foreach($file as $k=>$value){ 
        $v[] = $value; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: How do you get to your current array, what is the data your processing to get that from?

Comment: here is my foreach
`$url = Storage::disk('ftp')->allFiles('PM/PR_RFQNUM/');
        $v = [];
        foreach ($url as $key => $files) {
            //$file[] = $files;
            $xml = Storage::disk('ftp')->get($files);
            $file = Formatter::make($xml, Formatter::XML)->toArray();
            foreach($file as $k=>$value){
                $v[] = $value;
            }
}'`

@NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

This loop flattens the arrays and saves the records to the database:

```
foreach ($file as $value){ 
    $item = new SomeModel();
    $item->BANFN = $value['BANFN'];
    $item->BNFPO = $value['BNFPO'];
    $item->LIFNR_ID = $value['LIFNR_ID'];
    $item->STATUS_MSGTYP = $value['STATUS']['MSGTYP'];
    $item->STATUS_MSG = $value['STATUS']['MSG'];
    $item->save();
}
```